# How can I update my database on every mouse click through the frontend without sending too much requests?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, reactjs, express

**Following Problem:**

I want to create a little app for learning purposes that should do following things:

- Sign in with Google / FB / ..
- React / Redux fetches users clicker count + clicker count of the top 10 clickers
- You see a highscore table with the name and click count of top 10
- You see your clicker score and on every click you increase it
- **Now the challenging Part:**
- I want to update the database on every click (save the click to the user in the db)
- Update the highscore dynamically

  - So if another user clicks for example 10 times it should update his highscore

*I have a little chart to visualize this better (notice it has a 2nd tab on the bottom where I describe the stack I want to use) [image]*

**My thoughts**

I think I have to figure something out to not constantly update the database. Because if I update it on every click I see 2 problems:

- a TON of requests which is not good, right?
- if I click too fast it wouldn't be recognized right?

What I wonder is, I think I created something similiar but much more simplified a few months ago to test out firebase from google. I saved every click to firebase. I also had a listener with `on.("value")` or something like that, that created an action every time a new "click" comes in.

This worked perfectly, even when I clicked very fast. How is this possible? How is firebase doing this?

**Tech Stack I want to use**

- Node.js with Express for the Server
- MongoDB with Mongoose for Database (eventually mongodb cloud solution like mLab)
- React with Redux on the Frontend
- React Router
- Passport.js for Auth

**Now I would like to know if my approach I have in plan is going to work or if this would even work with that kind of stack. I didn't find anything on google that could help me out with this kind of question(s). So how can I update the db to reflect the data I see in my app but not creating an api call per click?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you looking into using **websockets**. This will probably be what you're looking for to help you update the database close to real-time. But make sure that you're keeping track of the current user's click in the React/Redux state.

Another solution is to throttle your REST api calls to update the database. The downside of this is the other users in your application won't see the real-time value of every other users. But since you're throttling it'll only be slightly behind.

https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-throttling-and-debouncing/

Comment: That looks promising to me. I'm just wondering, is there a way to make it work like I want to, so the users get a dynamically updated high score? Why is it working with firebase? It doesn't use a rest api or something like that, right?

Comment: Ah with Firebase I believe they're using a websocket. So instead of using a REST API you should look into adding a websocket which is what chat programs usually use to imitate real-time messaging

Comment: Ah websockets. I think that's exactly what I'm looking for! Thx

Comment: Yep just accepted it. Thx again. Websocket is indeed the perfect solution. Reading some docs at this moment :D

Comment: No problem! Good luck (:

Comment: If I may ask a second time. I can't get it into my head. I have a good idea how to establish a websocket connection and send + retrieve data from server to client and vice versa. Also storing this into the db is no problem. But how can I dynamically update the highscore? For this to happen I have to listen for changes in the db right? But that's not possible with mongodb as far as my google searches went. Any ideas how to tackle this?

Comment: What you want to do is keep track of all web sockets that is listening. Every time one of the web socket is going to send an update the db you want to call all the other web sockets and send them an update that the high score is changing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168528/discussion-between-kenneth-truong-and-geraltdiesocke).

Comment: Ah okay gotcha. So basically whenever you open the page the first time it will make  1 api request to retrieve the data in the db, establishes websocket connection and from now on he receives his highscore updates through websocket broadcasts? When he hard refreshes the page it then fetches the data again via API call and reconnects to websocket, right?